# How fix "Error: Failed to start application: Error starting the session."

Tags: iis, joomla3.0, sql-server-2017

I install joomla 3.9.11 on iis and my database in sql server.
But when I want to open this site show the following error:
"Error: Failed to start application: Error starting the session."
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

check that you installed below Extention in iis:

PHP

IIS URL Rewrite

MySQL

after installing all the extentions you need to convert .htaccess URL rewrite rule into iis URL rewrite rule.

1)open iis manager.

2)select your Joomla site or application.

3)select URL rewrite from the middle pane.

4)in URL rewrite module windows select import rules from the cation pane.

[image]

5)now click on three dots(...) and select your .htaccess file, then click on import and apply these changes.

[image]

then restart the iis.

the reason behind this error has something misconfiguration in your configuration.php file, a problem with your PHP version, or with your database itself.

log in to PHPMyAdmin and check your maximum database size limit.

Comment: I install two site on this server.One of them is on MySQL that work correctly but another one that is on SQL Server not work and display that error.If public $session_handler = 'database'; it does not work never but when set $session_handler='none'; When I refresh this site several time it work correct.

Comment: The error is only : "Error: Failed to start application: Error starting the session."

Comment: Apart of my configuration.php file is:   public $list_limit = '20';
 public $dbtype = 'sqlsrv';
 public $host = 'MyDatabaseServerName';
 public $user = 'MyUserName';
 public $password = 'MuPass';
 public $db = 'MYbdName';
 public $dbprefix = 'Mydbprefix';
 public $live_site = '';
 public $caching = '0';
 public $cache_handler = 'file';
 public $cachetime = '15';
 public $cache_platformprefix = '0';
 public $lifetime = '15';
 public $session_handler = 'none';
 public $shared_session = '0';

Comment: truncate the database sessions table to clear all entries and clear all from the browser history. if you still get the error then check the permission for configuration.php

Comment: My  sessions table is empty.I set  $session_handler='none' and session file create on my directory but the site not work correctly

Comment: please first make sure that connection string, username and password for the connecting database are correct. than try to check the Joomla log for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Set the $session_handler = 'database' in /configuration.php and check database connection